# Text.get() is returning .!entry in this specific order how to fix this

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, twilio

i wrote a code for users to validate that it is them using their phone number and otp but when i use the get function in tkinter to get the value of the entry it is always returning .!entry.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import random, tkinter as tk
def forgot_p():
    account_sid = 'ACCOUNT_SID'
    auth_token = 'AUTH_TOKEN'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    OTP = int(random.randint(1,1000000))
    message = client.messages \
                    .create(body=OTP,from_='+18888888888',to='+19999999999')
    message.sid
    global count
    count = 0
    def opt_checker(count):
        count+=1
        def clw():
            p_otp = int(opt_num.get())
            return p_otp
        if count >= 1:
            z = clw()
            if z == OTP:
                def new_password():
                    window_1 = tk.Tk()
                    label_1 = tk.Label(text='Please enter your new password twice')
                    text = tk.Entry()
                    text_1 = tk.Entry()
                    label_1.pack()
                    text.pack()
                    text_1.pack()
                    window_1.mainloop()
                    if text.get() == text_1.get():
                        print('password changed')
                    else:
                        window_1.destroy
                        new_password()
            else:
                print('didn\'t work')
    window = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(text='Please enter your OTP')
    opt_num = tk.Entry()
    button = tk.Button(text='Check OTP',command=lambda:[window.destroy(), opt_checker(count)])
    label.pack()
    opt_num.pack()
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

this is my code. I do not realize what is going wrong in this.

Comment: You have destroyed the root window before calling `opt_checker(...)`, so `opt_num` has already been destroyed when you tried to access it inside `clw()`.  You have similar issue inside `new_password()`, you tried to access tkinter widgets after the root window was destroyed.

Comment: using list to ruin many function in function like this `lambda:[window.destroy(), opt_checker(count)]`  is not preferred. You could add `window.destroy()` directly inside `def opt_checker()` - and then you can get values from `window` before you destroy it .

Comment: you have one mess in code - don't define functions inside other function because it is not readable. You could use normal `messagebox` to display message when value is wrong - and then you don't have to create another `Tk()` and you don't have to delete previous `Tk()` but you can reuse first `Tk()` to get correct values.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any action button to to fetch data, to invoke action of checking if one text is equal to another.
In `def new_password() :` function you only have `window`, `label`, `text1` and `text`. Create button to call action for checking `if text.get() == text1.get():`.

and put this line of code at the end of `def new_password() :`

```
window_1.mainloop()
```